# How to migrate frome CodeVision AVR to AVR Studio 5

Tags: c, avr, migrate

I have a legacy code that is set up as a CodeVision AVR project. I would like to migrate to AVR Studio or even better NetBeans (using the AVR tool chain or WinAVR).

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You should change many thing like:

**delay_xx(x);** to _delay_xx(x);
**there is no PINX.x**, you should define them
*and many so ...*

It's better for you to learn AVR Studio well and then migrate to it.
CodeVision is a bit simple than AVR Studio, but AVR Studio has many nice tools for debugging and a very nice editor. Also there are many projects for beginers all around the web.
*It's not too harda to migrate from CodeVisionAVR to AVR Studio 5! I did it months ago!!!*

As soon as possible migrate from CodeVisionAVR to AVR Studio 5.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question has been asked for years, but it might not be bad to answer it again.

Migrating from codevision avr to atmel studio or the new name microchip studio is not a difficult task.
Usually, those who do this have problems in how to define interrupts, find header file names, and bit access to registers (such as PINA.0), which can be solved very easily.

For the first two problems, you just need to do a simple search, and for the problem of registers, you need to be familiar with the C programming language to use [bit masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493411/what-is-bit-masking) or [pinters](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-c-and-c-set-1-introduction-arithmetic-and-array/) and [bitFields](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bit-fields-c/).

For example, for interrupt:

```
// In codeVisionAVR:
interrupt[EXT_INT0] void ext_int0_isr(void){}

// And in atmelStudio:
ISR(INT0_vect){}
```

And another example:

```
// In codeVisionAVR:
#include <io.h>

// In AtmelStudio:
#include <avr/io.h>
```

And finally Maybe this will help you:
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Getting-Started-with-Atmel-Studio7.pdf