# What is bit masking?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, terminology, bitmask

I am fairly new to C programming, and I encountered bit masking. What is the general concept and function of bit masking?

Examples are much appreciated.

Comment: I know links should not be posted, but wikipedia explanation is great: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

Comment: Related: *[What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work)*

Answer (score 365):

A mask defines which bits you want to keep, and which bits you want to clear.

Masking is the act of applying a mask to a value.  This is accomplished by doing:

- Bitwise ANDing in order to extract a subset of the bits in the value
- Bitwise ORing in order to set a subset of the bits in the value
- Bitwise XORing in order to toggle a subset of the bits in the value

Below is an example of extracting a subset of the bits in the value:

```
Mask:   00001111b
Value:  01010101b
```

Applying the mask to the value means that we want to clear the first (higher) 4 bits, and keep the last (lower) 4 bits. Thus we have extracted the lower 4 bits. The result is:

```
Mask:   00001111b
Value:  01010101b
Result: 00000101b
```

Masking is implemented using AND, so in C we get:

```
uint8_t stuff(...) {
  uint8_t mask = 0x0f;   // 00001111b
  uint8_t value = 0x55;  // 01010101b
  return mask & value;
}
```

Here is a fairly common use-case: Extracting individual bytes from a larger word.  We define the high-order bits in the word as the first byte. We use two operators for this, `&`, and `>>` (shift right).  This is how we can extract the four bytes from a 32-bit integer:

```
void more_stuff(uint32_t value) {             // Example value: 0x01020304
    uint32_t byte1 = (value >> 24);           // 0x01020304 >> 24 is 0x01 so
                                              // no masking is necessary
    uint32_t byte2 = (value >> 16) & 0xff;    // 0x01020304 >> 16 is 0x0102 so
                                              // we must mask to get 0x02
    uint32_t byte3 = (value >> 8)  & 0xff;    // 0x01020304 >> 8 is 0x010203 so
                                              // we must mask to get 0x03
    uint32_t byte4 = value & 0xff;            // here we only mask, no shifting
                                              // is necessary
    ...
}
```

Notice that you could switch the order of the operators above, you could first do the mask, then the shift.  The results are the same, but now you would have to use a different mask:

```
uint32_t byte3 = (value & 0xff00) >> 8;
```

Comment: Good answer but masking can also be applied for *setting* or *toggling* specific bits with OR or XOR operations and a suitable mask.

Comment: @Mr.Z: in C, C++ and related languages you would you the **bitwise AND** operator, which is written as `&`.

Comment: @Mr.Z For example: clear one byte of a uint32_t by masking the contents away: `#define MASK 0x000000FF .... my_uint32_t &= ~MASK`.

Comment: the `b` to indicate binary literal is not supported by all compilers, correct?

Comment: A part of confusion arises possibly because of poor choice of noun and verbs to describe what is really going on. For example, wouldn't a word like "Bitselector"  or "TargetBits" seem more suitable word to describe the object instead of using the word "Bitmask" ? Similarly, to describe the bit manipulation operations, using word such as "BitManipulate" seems more suitable word than the word "Masking" as the latter only makes sense for AND operations but not for XORING (toggle bits) or OR (set bits) which are rather bit manipulations or transformations but not masking operation.

Comment: so a mask is a byte used in a bitwise operation? why call it a "mask?"

Comment: [An Illustrated Guide to Bitwise Operators](https://medium.com/swlh/an-illustrated-guide-to-bitwise-operators-60b1b1ad5ac)

Comment: Suppose I used a bit mask in this way " if (value & 0x0F) ". And, suppose if I wanted to use this 'value' variable later, what would the variable 'value' contain? Will it contain it's original data or altered data after the masking operation?

Comment: @NamanDurve `value & 0x0f` does not contain any assignment so `value` does not change.

Answer (score 185):

**Masking** means to keep, change, or remove a desired part of information. Let’s see an image-masking operation; like this masking operation is removing anything that is not skin:

[image]

We are doing an *AND* operation in this example. There are also other masking operators—*OR* and *XOR*.

---

**Bitmasking** means imposing mask over bits. Here is a bitmasking with *AND*—

```
     1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1     input
(&)  0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0      mask
------------------------------
     0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0    output
```

So, only the middle four bits (as these bits are `1` in this mask) remain.

Let’s see this with *XOR*—

```
     1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1     input
(^)  0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0      mask
------------------------------
     1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1    output
```

Now, the middle four bits are flipped (`1` became `0`, `0` became `1`).

---

So, using a bitmask, we can access individual bits  [(examples)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit). Sometimes, this technique may also be used for improving performance. Take this for example-

```
bool isOdd(int i) {
    return i%2;
}
```

This function tells if an integer is odd/even. We can achieve the same result with more efficiency using a bit-mask—

```
bool isOdd(int i) {
    return i&1;
}
```

**Short Explanation**: If the [least significant bit](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/l/leastsb.htm) of a binary number is `1` then it is odd; for `0` it will be even. So, by doing *AND* with `1` we are removing all other bits except for the least significant bit, i.e.:

```
     55  ->  0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1     input
(&)   1  ->  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1      mask
---------------------------------------
      1  <-  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1    output
```

Comment: Also, to convert an integer to an odd no. if it is an even number: i=i|1. This comes in handy when we are trying to generate a sequence like 1, 3, 5,..., 2, 4, 6,...

Comment: You can also use the following operation to find the number with only the least significant bit from an integer: lsb = i&-i

Answer (score 161):

**Bits and Bytes**

In computing, numbers are internally represented in binary. This means, where you use an integer type for a variable, this will actually be represented internally as a summation of zeros and ones.

As you might know, a single bit represents one `0` or one `1`. A concatenation of eight of those bits represent a Byte, e.g. `00000101`, which is the number 5.
I presume you know how numbers are represented in binary, if not, take a look [here](http://l3d.cs.colorado.edu/courses/CSCI1200-96/binary.html).

In PHP a number is (mostly) 4 Bytes long. This means that your number actually uses 32 bits of the internal storage. But for simplicity reasons, throughout this answer I will use 8 bit numbers.

**Storing states in bits**

Now imagine you want to create a program that holds a state, which is based on multiple values that are one(`true`) or zero(`false`). One could store these values in different variables, may they be booleans or integers. **Or instead** use a single integer variable and use each bit of its internal 32 bits to represent the different true and falses.

An example:
`00000101`. Here the the first bit (reading from right to left) is true, which represents the first variable. The 2nd is false, which represents the 2nd variable. The third true. And so on...

This is a very compact way of storing data and has many usages.

**Bit Masking**

This is where bit masking comes in. It sounds complex but actually it's very simple.

Bit masking allows you to use operations that work on bit-level.

- Editing particular bits in a byte(s)
- Checking if particular bit values are present or not.

You actually apply a **mask** to a value, where in our case the value is our state `00000101` and the mask is again a binary number, which indicates the bits of interest.

By performing binary operations on the mask and the state one could achieve the following:

- The AND operator extracts a subset of the bits in the state
- The OR operator sets a subset of the bits in the state
- The XOR operator toggles a subset of the bits in the state

If we want to set a particular value to true, we could do this by using the OR operator and the following bit mask:

```
Mask:   10000000b
Value:  00000101b
---- OR ---------
Result: 10000101b
```

Or one could select a particular value from the state by using the AND operator:

```
Mask:   00001100b
Value:  00000101b
---- AND ---------
Result: 00000100b
```

I suggest you to take some deeper look into it and get familiar with the jargon. A good start may be [this](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18169) link.

Goodluck!

Comment: I'd dispute your terminology of "value" and "mask" there.  The mask is the thing that overrides -- ie  You start with a value, you mask it, and then obtain the result. (Plz swap it if you agree)

Answer (score 28):

It is just a number, as represented in binary. For example, let's say I have 8 boolean values (`true` or `false`) that I want to store. I could store it as an array of 8 booleans, or I could store it as a single byte (8 bits), each of which store one of the booleans (`0` = `false`, `1` = `true`).

At this point, I can easily manipulate my byte so that I can (1) set specific bits to be on or off (true or false), and (2) check whether specific bits are on or off.

- To set a bit to 1: `mask = mask | (1 << bitIndex)`
- To set a bit to 0: `mask = mask & ~(1 << bitIndex)`
- To get a bit (to be able to check it): `(mask & (1 << bitIndex)) != 0`

All of these operations use the left-shift operator, which moves bits up from least-significant to most-significant positions.

Answer (score 18):

In essence, Bitmask is a list of boolean flags (for example isAlive, isMoving, etc) compressed into a single field, usually an integer. It can cut quite a significant amount of JSON string size or memory footprint.

This can be significant especially in PHP where a single boolean in an array can take the same amount of RAM as an integer. There is a [very simple Bitmask guide](https://alemil.com/bitmask) that will explain step by step everything you need to know including how and when to use it.

Edit: Here's an archive link: https://archive.is/QwCUX, since the original site seems to be down.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a stab at the meaning of "Mask" when applied to computing with other data structures than bit arrays, and will use a few examples of how masks might apply. Bit masking works a certain way because they're defined in fixed size or have a presumed 0 value, so they do AND/OR masking (see @DJanssens great answer).

First an analogy to illustrate: start with an image of your face. When you look in the mirror? (square on) You see your face-- your cheeks, forehead, jaw, your eyes, etc.

Now you put on a mask (search images of "Venetian Half mask" if you don't know what a mask might look like).

What do you see in the mirror? You see the mask where the mask covers whats beneath. You your skin or jaw or whatever is not covered. *A mask obscures what it covers, but presents a set the size of the base.*

Ok now into computing we can also do masking across many data types. For example Objects, Arrays, Trees... They can be done additively (adding missing values from the mask, or only on the intersection of keys meaning if a key is not in the base, any mask is ignored).

**Eg 1 Objects**

```
Base = 
{
  "A": "baseA",
  "B": "baseB",
}
Mask = 
{
  "A": "maskA",
  "C": "maskC",
}
==> 
{
 "A": "maskA", // Masked / overridden by the mask
 "B": "baseB", // Pass through from base because not masked
 "C": "maskC", // Added because present in the mask (null/undefined in base)
}
```

**Eg2 Arrays** Assume `null` is a canary value, not a valid value

```
base = ["base1", "base2"]
mask = [null, "mask2", "mask3"]
==> ["base1", "mask2", "mask3"]
```

**Eg3 Trees** Assume `null` is a canary value, not a valid value

```
Base = 
  B
 /
A
 \ 
  C
Mask =
        E
       /
      D
     /
null 

Output = 
    E // Added by presence in mask
   /
  D // Override base value because present in mask
 /
A // Passthrough from base because `null` in mask means pass through
 \
  C // pass through because undefined in mask
```

**EG 4 Strings**

my colleague informed me of another key use of the word "mask" in computing which can be applied to strings, often in logs. The mask is usually not explicitly defined as an input value, but more like a function that redacts sensitive data

```
base = "[INFO] user logged in with user=stackoverflow@example.com password=123456"

mask(base) ==> "[INFO] user logged in with user=stackoverflow@example.com password=******"
```

(sometimes not matching masked length to also hide the length of the masked item)

see: https://github.com/gwpmad/mask-deep as an example of this usage of the word mask.