# int val=0xCAFE Test if at least three of last four bits (LSB) are on

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, mask

I'm trying to learn C on my own. I came across this exercise and i am studying to understand it. I have read about masking bits and in order to get the last four bits we should do val&0xF.I have read this post as well [What is Bit Masking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493411/what-is-masking). The part that i need an explanation is why the possible values are 0x7,0xB,0xD,0xE,0xF. I am studying the answer and i have read various articles. If someone is willing to explain to me this part i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because these are all the possible numbers with at least three of the last four bits on. If you write down every binary number from 0 to 15, you will see that these have at least three of the last four bits set:

- 0111 (0x7)
- 1011 (0xB)
- 1101 (0xD)
- 1110 (0xE)
- 1111 (0xF)

Think of it like this: every binary number from 0 to 6 has at most 2 bits set:

- 0 (0)
- 1 (1)
- 10 (2)
- 11 (3)
- 100 (4)
- 101 (5)
- 110 (6)

Thus, none of it matches the rule. From 7 up to 15, we have:

- 111 (7)
- 1000 (8)
- 1001 (9)
- 1010 (10)
- 1011 (11)
- 1100 (12)
- 1101 (13)
- 1110 (14)
- 1111 (15)

From these, only 7, 11, 13, 14 and 15 have three of the last four bits set.

This method is easy to implement:

```
int chk_last_bits2(unsigned x) {
    return ((x & 0x7) == 0x7) || 
            ((x & 0xB) == 0xB) || 
            ((x & 0xD) == 0xD) || 
            ((x & 0xE) == 0xE) || 
            ((x & 0xF) == 0xF);
}
```

Note that we have to explicitly test for equality for each case. For example, `x & 0xB` will return a non-zero value for every number with any of `1011` bits set. This is not what we want, we want all of them to be on, which can be tested with equality.

Another possible solution would be:

```
int chk_last_bits(unsigned x) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1, j = 0; i < 32; i <<= 1)
        if (i & x)
            j++;
    return j >= 3;
}
```

Since you're learning C, I'll leave this one for you to try to understand.

Comment: Your first ("easy to implement") function will not work - it will return `true` for every `(x & 0x0f) != 0`. You probably meant `(x & 0x0f) == 7` for the first comparison, and so on.

Comment: Oops!! How did I miss that? Thanks for noticing, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Masking means filtering bits and keeping only some of them, which are of interest, as you will have understood.

Let's say that you have a variable `something` and a `mask`, both are `unsigned` values: `something & mask` will return a value whose bits are `0` where the mask is `0` and the value they had in `something` where the mask is `1`. This is the *and mask*.

To understand why you use those particular values, you have to recall how bitwise operations (`&`, `|`...) work in C. When you write `a & b`, then the corresponding bits of the two variables are orderly combined using the specified logical operator. For instance, if `a` is `10001010` and `b` is `00000011`, then `a & b` is `00000010` (orderly, `1 and 0, 0 and 0, 0 and 0, 0 and 0, 1 and 0, 0 and 0, 1 and 1, 0 and 1`).

If you understood that, then you can understand what those masks will select. Consider their binary representation:

> ```
> 0x7 --> ...00000111 --> the three LSBs
> 0xb --> ...00001011 --> the first, second and fourth LSBs
> 0xd --> ...00001101 --> the first, third and fourth LSBs
> 0xe --> ...00001110 --> the second, third and fourth LSBs
> 0xf --> ...00001111 --> the 4 LSBs
> ```

This was for *and masking*, which is for extracting values (refer to the answer you linked).  *xor* and *or* masking would work similarly, just recall how the logical function behaves.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    /*
        32 Bit binary: 00000000000000001100101011111110
        Decimal: 51966
    */

    int val = 0xCAFE;

    /*
        Note:
            First it does loop, after that it shifts the bits of `i`,
            so `i` is 1 at the beginning.
            When shifting operator appears always think of bits.

        Step 1
        Decimal: i = 1
        32 Bit binary: 00000000000000000000000000000001

        Step 2
        Decimal: 1 << 1 = 2
        32 Bit binary: 00000000000000000000000000000010

        Step 3
        Decimal: 2 << 1 = 4
        32 Bit binary: 00000000000000000000000000000100

        ... and so on ... 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, stop.

        This indicates 2^n.

        ----------------------------------------------------------------

        Inside the for loop we run the AND operator to find out
        which bits are `on` and which are `off`.

        AND only works if both are true.

        Step 1:
        Last bit

            00000000000000000000000000000001
        AND 00000000000000001100101011111110
            ---------------------------------
            00000000000000000000000000000000

        Decimal: 1
        Second last bit

        Step 2:

            00000000000000000000000000000010
        AND 00000000000000001100101011111110
            ---------------------------------
            00000000000000000000000000000010

        Decimal: 2

        ... and so on ...

        As we can see we gradually check for last 4 bits until
        we reach the 4th loop 2^4 = 32 and the loop stops.

    */

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < 32; i = i << 1) {

        /* 
            You can simply add a counter over here
            and return the value at the end.
        */
        printf("%d\n", i & val);
    }
}
```