# Using more than one flag in python re.findall

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I would like to use more than one flag with the `re.findall` function. More specifically, I would like to use the `IGNORECASE` and `DOTALL` flags at the same time.

```
x = re.findall(r'CAT.+?END', 'Cat \n eND', (re.I, re.DOTALL))
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#78>", line 1, in <module>
    x = re.findall(r'CAT.+?END','Cat \n eND',(re.I,re.DOTALL))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 243, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sre_compile.py", line 500, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sre_parse.py", line 673, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sre_parse.py", line 308, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sre_parse.py", line 401, in _parse
    if state.flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Is there a way to use more than one flag ?

Comment: See the documentation for [re.compile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile).

Comment: In addition to @PeterWood's link: https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags

Comment: If you use a lot of regex, its always better to use in-line modifiers if you can. Mostly because you are not actually using _`FLAGS`_ with the FindAll function, they are being passed to and attached to the Regular Expression object. The modifiers bind to the regex object, not the regex usage functions. So, if you cut and paste a regex somewhere else, you don't have to worry about flags at all. So, `r'(?si)CAT.+?END'` is the best way.

Comment: @PeterWood, the documentation for 3.8.1 is useless for this question.

Comment: @ZachYoung I answered the question 5 1/2 years ago.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Yes, but you have to OR them together:

```py
x = re.findall(pattern=r'CAT.+?END', string='Cat \n eND', flags=re.I | re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: I always encourage everybody to use `flags=` when passing flags. If you don't, `my_regex.search` and `my_regex.match` will interpret the flags (which are `int`s internally) as the `pos` argument. So you'll mean to be doing `my_regex.search(my_str, re.DOTALL)`, but that'll be interpreted as `my_regex.search(my_str, pos=16)`. If you always use `flags=`, you'll get an error in the above, and you'll properly use `re.search` instead.

Comment: In the official docs is the 2nd sentence under <https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile>

Comment: Hi AMC and @mipadi, why is OR necessary? What is the difference if I use AND instead?

Comment: @ValerioFiccadenti: They are [bit masks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10493604/28804) so if you AND them together you will not end up with the right value.

Comment: Most flags are available as inline flags for those who dislike using bitwise operators when passing arguments.

Answer (score 20):

You can't put the flags within a tuple. Use the pipe character (OR operand) within your flags:

```
x = re.findall(r'CAT.+?END','Cat \n eND',flags=re.I | re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 18):

> Is there a way to use more than one flag ?

It wasn't mentioned, but you can use [**inline `(?...)` modifiers**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers) as well.

```
x = re.findall(r'(?si)CAT.+?END', 'Cat \n eND')
```