# Better explanation of $convmap in mb_encode_numericentity()

Tags: php, collation, html-entities, html-encode

The description given to this parameter, `convmap`, for method `mb_encode_numericentity` in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php) is vague to me. Would somebody help with a better explanation of this, or maybe "dumb it down" if it should be sufficient for me? What is the meaning of the array elements used in this parameter? Example 1 in the manpage has

```
<?php
$convmap = array (
 int start_code1, int end_code1, int offset1, int mask1,
 int start_code2, int end_code2, int offset2, int mask2,
 ........
 int start_codeN, int end_codeN, int offsetN, int maskN );
// Specify Unicode value for start_codeN and end_codeN
// Add offsetN to value and take bit-wise 'AND' with maskN, then
// it converts value to numeric string reference.
?>
```

which is helpful, but then I see a lot of usage examples like `array(0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff);` which throws me off. Does that mean the offset would be `0` and the mask would be `0xffff`, if so, does offset mean number of characters in the string to start converting, and what does `mask` mean in this context?

Comment: At first glance, it would seem that both [Example #1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php#refsect1-function.mb-encode-numericentity-examples) and [Example #2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php#refsect1-function.mb-encode-numericentity-examples) on that page show the same format _(but shown with either a single line or many lines)_, meaning that the `offset` would be `0` and the `mask` would be `0xffff` in your example. The `$convmap` in those examples seems to show that you can include as many "lines" _("sets" of four values)_ as necessary.

Comment: @summea Thanks summea. What exactly does `mask` mean in this context? I updated my question for that.

Comment: There may be more specific reasons for using the `offset` and `mask` values in the `convmap`, but I hope the answer below helps a bit!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking down the [rabbit hole](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/250938e2d35fc54161a18167b7901c5e3b574371/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl/mbfilter.c#L2687), it appears that the [comments in the documentation for `mb_encode_numericentity`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php#refsect1-function.mb-encode-numericentity-examples) are accurate, though somewhat cryptic.

> The four major parts to the `convmap` appear to be:
>
> `start_code`: The map affects items starting from this character code.
>   `end_code`: The map affects items up to this character code.
>   `offset`: Add a specific offset amount *(positive or negative)* for this character code.
>   `mask`: Value to be used for mask operation *(character code **bitwise AND** mask value)*.

Character codes can be visualized via character tables such as [this Codepage Layout example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) for `ISO-8859-1` encoding. *(`ISO-8859-1` is the encoding used in the original PHP documentation [Example #2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php#refsect1-function.mb-encode-numericentity-examples).)* Looking at this encoding table, we can see that the `convmap` is only meant to affect character code items that start from `0x80` *(which appears to be blank for this particular encoding)* to the final character in this encoding `0xff` *(which appears to be `ÿ`)*.

In order to better understand the **offset** and **mask** features of `convmap`, here are some examples of how offset and mask affect character codes *(and in the examples below, our `character code` has a defined value of `162`)*:

## Plain Example:

```
<?php    
$original_str = "¢";
$convmap = array(0x00, 0xff, 0, 0xff);
$converted_str = mb_encode_numericentity($original_str, $convmap, "UTF-8");
echo "original:  $original_str\n";
echo "converted: $converted_str\n";
?>
```

> ### Result:
>
> ```
> original:  ¢
> converted: &#162;
> ```

---

## Offset Example:

```
<?php
$original_str = "¢";
$convmap = array(0x00, 0xff, 1, 0xff);
$converted_str = mb_encode_numericentity($original_str, $convmap, "UTF-8");
echo "original:  $original_str\n";
echo "converted: $converted_str\n";
?>
```

> ### Result:
>
> ```
> original:  ¢
> converted: &#163;
> ```

#### Notes:

The `offset` seems to allow for a finer grain of control for the current `start_code` and `end_code` section of items-to-convert. For example, you might have some particular reason you need to add an offset for a certain line of character codes in your `convmap`, but then you might need to ignore that offset for another line in your `convmap`.

---

## Mask Example:

```
<?php
// Mask Example 1
$original_str = "¢";
$convmap = array(0x00, 0xff, 0, 0xf0);
$converted_str = mb_encode_numericentity($original_str, $convmap, "UTF-8");
echo "original:  $original_str\n";
echo "converted: $converted_str\n\n";

// Mask Example 2
$convmap = array(0x00, 0xff, 0, 0x0f);
$converted_str = mb_encode_numericentity($original_str, $convmap, "UTF-8");
echo "original:  $original_str\n";
echo "converted: $converted_str\n\n";

// Mask Example 3
$convmap = array(0x00, 0xff, 0, 0x00);
$converted_str = mb_encode_numericentity($original_str, $convmap, "UTF-8");
echo "original:  $original_str\n";
echo "converted: $converted_str\n";
?>
```

> ### Result:
>
> ```
> original:  ¢
> converted: &#160;
>
> original:  ¢
> converted: &#2;
>
> original:  ¢
> converted: &#0;
> ```

#### Notes:

This answer does not intend to cover [masking in great detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)), but masking can help [keep or remove certain bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10493604) from a given value.

#### Mask Example 1

So in the first mask example `0xf0`, the `f` indicates that we want to keep the values on the left side of the binary value. Here, `f` has a binary value of `1111` and `0` has a binary value of `0000`--together becoming a value of `11110000`.

Then, when we do a bitwise AND operation with our `character code` *(in this case, `162`, which has a binary value of `10100010`)* the bitwise operation looks like this:

```
  11110000
& 10100010
----------
  10100000
```

And when converted back to its decimal value, `10100000` is `160`.

Therefore, we've effectively kept the "left side" of the bits from the original `character code` value, and have gotten rid of the "right side" of the bits.

#### Mask Example 2

In the second mask example, the mask `0x0f` *(which has a binary value of `00001111`)* in the bitwise AND operation would have the following binary result:

```
  00001111
& 10100010
----------
  00000010
```

Which, when converted back to its decimal value, is `2`.

Therefore, we've effectively kept the "right side" of the bits from the original `character code` value, and have gotten rid of the "left side" of the bits.

#### Mask Example 3

Finally, the third mask example shows what happens when using a mask of `0x00` *(which is `00000000` in binary)* in the bitwise AND operation:

```
  00000000
& 10100010
----------
  00000000
```

Which results in `0`.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @NickRolando Oh, not me! But I'm glad this helped!