# How to check how many numbers a bit flag / bit mask contains

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am storing all my equipped guns using a bit flag, and was just wondering if it was possible to check how many numbers are contained in a bit flag.

e.g. :

13 would contain 1, 4, and 8

NOTE:
I am new to bit flags so my question might not make too much sense or I might have used the wrong terminology, if so just let me know and I will be happy to change it.

Comment: Why does 13 contain 1, 4 and 8?

Comment: 1+4+8 = 13.....

Comment: 10+3 = 13 why doesn't that count?

Comment: OP meant bitmask @rene

Comment: I'm trying to teach some fishing here @M.kazemAkhgary but thanks for giving that. From here it is easy.

Comment: no because it goes 1,2,4,8,16 and so on

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx - this is exactly what a bitwise and between your value and the "contained" number is for

Comment: Ok, why does it go like that? Because if you answered that you're at the solution.

Comment: I don't know, like I said I'm new to bit masks, I honestly only know how and not why, thats my problem

Comment: @Peyton if you're newbie, then try to comprehend [what bit masking is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493411)

Comment: ok thank you, but can someone please answer my question?

Comment: Do you understand binary numbers and how they are relevant to the question at hand? If you don't, study them and then ask again if you are still encountering problems. This isn't a place where people will simply solve your problems. You've received a few pointers of where you should look to learn to solve your problem. Now go ahead and try.

Comment: Given that "guns" are probably something you want to enumerate or iterate over from time to time, and enumerations in C# are not exactly iteration-friendly, are you sure you want to store that value as a set of bit flags?

Comment: BitOperations.PopCount(item.ProcessorMask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are asking:

> How many numbers are contained in a bit flag?

This should work:

```
int CountBits(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        int has = n & 1;
        if (has == 1) 
        {
            count ++ ;
        }

    } while((n >>= 1) != 0);

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will never end if high bit is set initially, i.e. `n` is negative.

Comment: @IvanStoev Absolutely right. However, since OP stroing equipped guns using a bit flag the input value should be negative unless he uses signbit.

Comment: @IvanStoev actually changing condition to `(n >>= 1) != 0` should eliminate the problem.

Comment: Not really because `>>` is duplicating the sign bit. What you wrote works for `uint` but not for `int` :)

Comment: @IvanStoev oh now I understand. thanks man.

Comment: BitOperations.PopCount(item.ProcessorMask)

Answer (score 0):

I quickly wrote a method that does exactly what you want, certainly not the best though:

```
public static List<int> DecomposeBitFlag(int flag) {
    var bitStr = Convert.ToString(flag, 2);
    var returnValue = new List<int>();
    for(var i = 0 ; i < bitStr.Length ; i++) {
        if (bitStr[bitStr.Length - i - 1] == '1') {
            returnValue.Add((int)Math.Pow(2, i));
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

How it works:

I first convert the integer parameter to a binary string. For each of the "1"s in the string, add 2 to the power i to the return value list. i is the index of the "1" in the reversed string.

EDIT:

If you only want to know the number of bits, this will do:

```
public static int BitFlagBitCount(int flag) {
    var bitStr = Convert.ToString(flag, 2);
    return bitStr.Count(c => c == '1');
}
```

Comment: OK thanks... I will try it out

Comment: so this method returns a list right?

Comment: @Peyton Yes. It returns a list that contains all the bits that make up the flag.

Comment: Ok and then I can just get the length of the list to find out how many different numbers are in my bit flag or whatever

Comment: @Peyton If you _only_ want the number of bits, you don't even need to add the number to the list! Just `Count` the number of "1"s

Comment: @Peyton See my edited answer

Comment: Although this does work, it is done in a horrible way :)

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Yes there certainly is a better way to do it. I just love string manipulation...