# Why use "& 0xff" in CPython when write byte to file, what it does?

Tags: python, cpython

such as:

```
static void w_long(long x, WFILE *p)
{
    w_byte((char)( x      & 0xff), p);
    w_byte((char)((x>> 8) & 0xff), p);
    w_byte((char)((x>>16) & 0xff), p);
    w_byte((char)((x>>24) & 0xff), p);
}
```

And why the pyc file is unreadable, where is the const text/string ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Bit Masking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493411/what-is-bit-masking)

Comment: Your second question is hard to understand.  You should be asking a single question per question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`& 0xff` takes the last 8 bits (or one byte) from the number. That makes sure you write only one byte at a time to the file (and in that case, uses for little endian byte-order storing).

`0xff` is `1111 1111` in binary. Executing logical `and` with it will turn on all the bits that are `1` in `x` and are within the last 8 bits.

---

For example:

```
x = 0010 0100 1001 0111
                         &
              1111 1111
    -------------------
    0000 0000 1001 0111
```