# How to read two last bits from Int8?

Tags: swift

How can I get the last *two bits* from `Int8`?

I would like to convert `00110010` to `00000010`.

Comment: Bit masking maybe?

Comment: Make a AND: `00110010 & 00000011 = 00000010`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Bit Masking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493411/what-is-bit-masking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *bitwise and* operator, `&`:

```
let byte: Int8 = 0b0011_0010
let masked = byte & 0b0000_0011
print(String(masked, radix: 2)) // => 10
```

Comment: Curious - why don't you use the `byte` variable on the 2nd line? Typo?

Comment: @rmaddy Yep, could you fix pls? On mobile