# How to write and read specific bit of a 32 bit register

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm new to bit operations and trying to experiment little bit.

let's say I have a 32 bit register which is constructed as follows:

```
Bit 31:12 RESERVED
Bit 11    CONFIG1
Bit 10    CONFIG2
Bit 9:0   DATA
```

There exists already a Function to write data into the register:

```
 #define WR_REG_32(address, value)    (*((volatile u32 *)(address)) = (value))
```

I would like to write the value 0x0 at Bit 10 (CONFIG2). The value should be in the format like for example:

```
0x00005000
```

So, how to know what hex value to use in order to write to Bit 10 the value 0x0 without touching the other bits?

Also, what is the easiest way to read from the 32 bit register only the values from bit 0 - 9 ?

Comment: Bitwise operations as shift, and, or etc. are made for this purpose. If register has 32 bits, 32 bits you will read. Only then you can use aforementioned operations to get bits you want.

Comment: from the top of the Related list: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit?rq=1)...

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493411/what-is-bit-masking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read first the register to write the same bits, except the bit 10 forced to zero.

To force a bit to zero, bit 10, you have to use the bitwise `AND` between the current value and all-bits-to-1-except-bit-10 (zero)

```
 newValue = currentValue & ~(1<<10)
```

The `~` operator invert bits. `&` is bitwise AND. Using the macro,

```
value = RD_REG_32(address)    ; To read the current value
WR_REG_32(address, value & ~(1<<10))
```

`RD_REG_32` to read the current value.

To read the bits 0~9, set the others to 0

```
(read value from register)
value &= 0x3FF;     // keeps only the first 10 bits, from 0 to 9
```

---

Read also Eric's comment below. Your architecture might impact the way you can deal with 32 bits values.

Comment: `int` may be 16 bits, in which case `~(1<<10)` evaluates to `~1024` and then `64512` (assuming two’s complement), and then `value & ~(1<<10)` clears the high 16 bits of `value`. Generally, when using bitwise operations, it is good to use an unsigned type of the desired width, as with `value & ~((u32) 1 << 10)`.