# How to build a reverse bitwise operation

Tags: java, c#, c++

### Bitwise Reverse Operation

I have a group of **encrypted bytes** which I can decrypt with the following function:

```
        byte b = (byte) (encrypted & 0xFF);
        return b >> 5 & 0x7 | (b & 0x1F) << 3;
    }
      
    0x51 >> 5 & 0x7 | 0x51 & 0x1F << 3 = 0x98
    ^                 ^
```

At first glance, it precedes a complex operation, so I have decided to separate it into parts.

I need to get the reverse operation. I know how byte operations work; the displacements seem easy to reverse but the AND are not more difficult. Many thought in previous threads that you cannot but would like to know your opinions about it.

I have noticed that the operation `(b & 0x1F)` only returns numbers of `0x0` and `0x1F` and when it reaches `0x20`  restarts at `0x0`, so successively until `0x39` that returns `0x20` and `0x40` naturally returns `0x0`.

Thinking about a possible solution, I have to know of a function `"x & y = z"` that I know "y" and "z", for example `"x + 0x1F = 0x1A"` can determine that the original byte could be any of the next `{0x1A, 0x3A, 0x5A, 0x7A, 0x9A, 0xBA, 0xDA, 0xFA}`, but now the question is how do I select the correct one.

To try to answer this question `0xA1 & 0x1F = 0x1` , assuming that of `"x & y = z"`, we only know `y` and `"z"` the possible x would only be `{0x1, 0x21, 0x41, 0x61, 0x81, 0xA1, 0xC1, 0xE1}`, as you can see the answer is between 8 possible bytes.

Maybe I am posing the problem badly but I cannot build a reverse operation. Can you give me your opinion or explain how to put together an operation of this type?

Comment: Overall it's a rotate, if you look at it like that then it's easy to reverse

Comment: If you do 1110 and 0100 you cannot reverse , from the resulting 0100, if the original was 1110 or 0100, or 0101, it's just impossible. It's not a biunique projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find a reverse operation, you should try looking at what the code is doing *on the whole*, instead of the individual operations.

The left operand of `|` says,

> Shift `b` 5 places to the right `>> 5` then clear all the bits except the least significant three bits `& 0x7`. Note that 7 is 111 in binary.

The above gets the most significant 3 bits of `b` and moves them all the way to the right. 1010 1100 would become 0000 0101.

The right operand of `|` says,

> Clear all the bits except `b`'s least significant 5 bits, and then shift `b` 3 places to the left. Note that 1F is 0001 1111 in binary.

This gets the least significant 5 bits of `b` then moves all the way to the left. 1010 1100 would become 0110 0000.

And finally, the `|` combines the two results together.

So on a high level of abstraction, this code just switches the first 3 and last 5 bits in a byte. 1110 0000 would become 0000 0111.

To reverse this, just switch the first 5, and last 3 bits.

```
byte b = (byte) (decrypted & 0xFF);
return b >> 3 & 0x1F | (b & 0x7) << 5;
```

You might want to learn about [Bit Masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493411/what-is-bit-masking) if you find this answer confusing.

Comment: the `& 0x1F` and `& 0x7` are redundant, They are there to null the bits, but a shift should pull `0`s in this case, so this just makes it more complicated.

Comment: @Dimfred IIRC Java does an arithmetic shift, not a logical shift, so it’s not necessarily 0s.

Comment: Ah okay, should have added C++ to my comment. But good to know that things work entirely different in java.

Answer (score 0):

Just compute array of 256 bytes: `m_encrypt`; byte -> encrypted byte

If it is one-to-one then it is reversable, otherwise it isn't.

Compute decryption array `m_decrypt` via

```
for(int i=0; i< 256; i++)
  m_decrypt[m_encrypt[i]] = i;
```

Comment: Naturally, in this way we can easily obtain all possible bytes, but this generates 8 possibilities, for example for a 0x1A byte, there are three 8 possible combinations that operating with 0x1F would generate 0x1A in response:

`{ 0x1A, 0x3A, 0x5A, 0x7A, 0x9A, 0xBA, 0xDA, 0xFA }`
For example if I do `0x9A & 0x1F = 0x1A`

Is the question as if `x & y = z` select the correct one if I only know "y" and "z"?

Maybe I am focusing the problem badly and I need to see it from another angle. Maybe I have to see the result of the complete function to deduce some mathematical operation.