# C - XMPLAB DDRD/DDRB not assignable error

Tags: c, arduino, translation, pic, mplab

I am working on a project translating some Arduino code of a RFM Hopper Transmissor to C, but there are few concepts that I don't fully understand like the DDRB and DDRD.

For example, I call these two methods:

```
InputSDIO();
OutputSDIO();
```

which are declared in another file with these lines:

```
#define InputSDIO() (DDRB &= (~_SDIO))
#define OutputSDIO() (DDRB |= (_SDIO))
```

and it gives me the following error

> error: expression is not assignable

Furthermore, I also get the same error from this call,

```
RX_ANTOut();
```

which is defined in another file with the following line:

```
#define RX_ANTOut() (DDRD |= (RX_ANT))
```

As I said, the code comes from an Arduino project of a transmissor. If you need any more info or if my question could be more detailed feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

In `DDRB` and `DDRD` the *DDR* is **d**ata **d**irection **r**egister and it determines if a pin is an input or output (the uC is an Atmel AVR), `DDRB` is the DDR of port B, `DDRD` of port D. `SDIO` is a port configuration that is usually implemented as a **bitmask**. The operators `&=` and `|=` have the same meaning as `+=`, `-=`,... so i.e. `a &= b` means `a = a & b` and so `DDRB &= (~SDIO)` is equivalent to `DDRB = DDRB & (~SDIO)` what is a common way of *bitmasking* the `~` is logical negation `&` is logical AND, `|` is logical OR.

`SDIO` is an 8 bit (? what AVR model exactly is this ? ) binary number something like `0b01110010` that masks the pins of the port, i.e. port D

**https://blog.podkalicki.com/bit-level-operations-bit-flags-and-bit-masks/**, 
[What is Bit Masking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493411/what-is-bit-masking)

In the datasheet of the ATmega128RFA1 (https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/AVR/ATmega128RFA1_Datasheeta.pdf) the function of the DDRs is on page 191 in chapter *14.2.2 Configuring the Pin*