# Python script to convert octal to string eg octal(755) to (rwxr-xr-x). Stuck at adding the dash seperator

Tags: python

Below is the script printing the converted octal to string. I would appreciate suggestion on how to add the - separator to the string on each permission (r/w/x)

```py
def octal_to_string(octal):
    result = ""
    value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")]
    #Iterating over each digit in octal
    for digit in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:

        #Checking for each of permission values
        for value, letter in value_letters:
            if digit >= value:
                result += letter
                digit -= value
            else:
                pass
    return result
```

I currently get:

```
In [7]: octal_to_string(755)
Out[7]: 'rwxrxrx'

In [8]: octal_to_string(644)
Out[8]: 'rwrr'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick fix, just replace the `pass` with `result += '-'`; for every permission test that is *False* you can simply insert a dash:

```
for value, letter in value_letters:
    if digit >= value:
        result += letter
        digit -= value
    else:
        result += '-'
```

I'd just use [*bit masking*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493411/what-is-bit-masking) however, with the [`&` bitwise and operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations):

```
for value, letter in value_letters:
    result += letter if digit & value else '-'
```

This works because `4`, `2` and `1` are the decimal (and octal) values for numbers with each *one* of the 3 bits set to 1, the others to 0. `digit & 4` is only going to produce `4` *or* `0`, depending on the value of the 3rd bit from the right being set in `digit` or not. Since [`0` is false, and `4` is a true value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), this lets you test if the right bit is set and so decide between the permission letter and `-`. I used a [*conditional expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to return either in a single line.

Next, I'd not use a list comprehension to convert the input value into octal digits; just use `map()` here to *lazily* convert without creating an additional list object:

```
for digit in map(int, str(octal)):
```

Next, try to avoid using string concatenation in a loop; although Python has some optimisations in place to avoid the worst case performance in simple situations, you can easily miss out on that optimisation. Best to append characters to a *list* then use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to create the final string in one step.

Put together into a complete function:

```
def octal_to_string(octal):
    result = []
    for digit in map(int, str(octal)):
        for value, letter in ((4, "r"), (2, "w"), (1, "x")):
            result.append(letter if digit & value else "-")
    return "".join(result)
```

Demo:

```
>>> octal_to_string(755)
'rwxr-xr-x'
>>> octal_to_string(644)
'rw-r--r--'
```

Now, what the function *accepts* are *decimal* numbers, not octal numbers. From an API design you'd really want to either accept *strings* only (containing digits representing an octal value), or if you do accept an integer, then you should treat that value as *decimal* and use `0o` octal notation:

```
>>> 0o755  # actual octal number
493
>>> format(0o755, "o")  # string representing value in octal notation
'755'
```

If you do so, just change `str(octal)` into `format(octal, 'o')` to get the octal digits:

```
>>> octal = 0o755
>>> for digit in map(int, format(octal, "o")):
...     print(digit)
...
...
7
5
5
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the `pass` to `result += "-"`:

```py
def octal_to_string(octal): 
    result = "" 
    value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")] 
    #Iterating over each digit in octal 
    for digit in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]: 

        #Checking for each of permission values 
        for value, letter in value_letters: 
            if digit >= value: 
                result += letter 
                digit -= value 
            else: 
                result += "-" 
    return result 

print(octal_to_string(755))
```

Output:

```
rwxr-xr-x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def octal_to_string(octal):
    result = ""
    value_letters = [(4,"r"),(2,"w"),(1,"x")]
    # Iterate over each of the digits in octal
    for digits in [int(n) for n in str(octal)]:
        # Check for each of the permissions values
        for value, letter in value_letters:
            if digits >= value:
                result += letter
                digits -= value
            else:
                result += "-"
    return result
```