# changing the b the digit of binary number in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c

how can I convert the x position digit of binary number to for example 1 or 0 without using loop...
x is an integer number and
position is where you change the binary number

Comment: You could use bit-shift; `unsigned value = (x >> position) & 1;`.

Comment: An efficient way is [bit masking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10493411/2472827).

Comment: Or if you don't want to write the bitmasking code yourself : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

Comment: It's important to understand that there isn't such a thing as a "binary number". Binary is a *way to represent* the number. If I write `23` or `0x17` or `0x10111` or `twenty-three` I am talking about the same thing; and by writing it in different ways, I *didn't change* the thing.

Comment: @royanmaeri Did the answer help or do you want me to explain anything in more detail?

Answer (score 3):

- Toggle the bit `pos` in `num`:

  ```
  num ^= 1ULL << pos;       // ^ is xor
  ```
- Set the bit `pos` in `num`:

  ```
  num |= 1ULL << pos;       // | is bitwise or
  ```
- Clear the bit `pos` in `num`:

  ```
  num &= ~(1ULL << pos);    // & is bitwise and, ~ is bitwise not
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to change the x-th digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int input; 
    int x=2;//number of the digit that you want to change
    int y=0;//x-th digit will be changed to this 
    scanf("%d",&input);
    int left_digits; //the digits left to the (x-1)-th digit 
    int right_digits;//the x-1 first digits 
    left_digits=input>>x-1;
    right_digits=input-(left_digits<<x-1);
    left_digits-=left_digits%2;
    left_digits+=y;
    int ans=(left_digits<<x-1)+right_digits;
    printf("%d",ans);
}
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated. `if (y) input |= 1 << x; else input &= ~1 << x;` (suggested in the other answer) should do the same thing.