# data.append(pixel[0] & 0b11), what do "0b11" and "&" do here?

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, endianness, steganography

i tried to change the last 3 units of pixels. And every unit i could change up to 3 bytes, i looked up to the tutorial and it only showed me the code, not the explanation. why "&" and "0b11" are there.0b11 was the binary code of 3

Comment: Welcome to SO! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What is your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would help if you could cite the URL you were reading, so we can read it, too, putting us all on the same page. And please post some of the code you're working with, which applies that binary 0x03 mask to some pixels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is bit masking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493411/what-is-bit-masking)