# Breaking a decimal number into 2 other decimal numbers using bitwise operations

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

To assume tha I have number 54998 which in binar is:

```
54998=11010110 11010110
```

And now I have to break this number into 2 other numbers of the size of 8 bytes in binar,for example:

```
11010110=214 and 11010110=214
```

Any ideas to do it in C?

I thought about moving the number 8 bites to the right and finding the first number,but are there any other ways to do this?

```
number>>8;
```

Comment: What books or tutorials are you reading? What, if any, classes are you taking? What have they taught you about bitwise operations in C? What have they said about shifting and *masking*?

Comment: Assuming NUM is a 2-byte integer you can get he High-Order Byte by `NUM >> 8` and the Low-Order Byte by `NUM & 0xFF`.

Comment: Do you need an answer to also cover numbers outside the obvious range of 0...65535, or can we disregard those?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am taking courses at university but we learned nothing about masks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [bit masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493411/what-is-bit-masking/10493604#10493604):

```c
void more_stuff(uint32_t value) {             // Example value: 0x010203
    uint32_t byte1 = (value >> 16);           // 0x010203 >> 16 is 0x01 so
                                              // no masking is necessary
    uint32_t byte2 = (value >> 8) & 0xff;     // 0x010203 >> 8 is 0x0102 so
                                              // we must mask to get 0x02
    uint32_t byte3 = value & 0xff;            // here we only mask, no shifting
                                              // is necessary
}
```