# Bit masking & garbage bits

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation

In the topic "Using the Bitwise Logical Operators" from Herbert Schildt's Java: The Complete Reference, Schildt makes the conjunction `~a & 0x0f` in order to "*reduce its value* [`~a`] *to less than 16, so it can be printed by use of the binary array*".

```java
class BitLogic {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] binary = {
    "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
    "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"
    };
    int a = 3; // 0 + 2 + 1 or 0011 in binary
    int b = 6; // 4 + 2 + 0 or 0110 in binary
    /* ... */
    int g = ~a & 0x0f;

    /* ... */
    System.out.println(" ~a = " + binary[g]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```java
~a = 1100
```

`~a`, by itself, doesn't exceed 4 bits, because its value is 1100 (or 12, in decimal), and a conjunction between `~a` and `0x0f` (0000 1111) should be an identity operation, since every bit of `~a` is multiplied by one, hence making `~a` depending exclusively on its own values. Am I missing something?

So, how does `0x0f` reduce the value of `~a` to be less than 16? Wouldn't `~a` still have the value 1100 without this conjunction?

Comment: What happens when you just print `~a` without the `& 0x0f`? You do realize that Java ints are 32 bits, correct?

Comment: It throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with the message: *Index -4 out of bounds for length 16*.

Comment: Think of the lower byte as a bit mask - all 1s.

Comment: Maybe that's what I'm missing, then. I don't know yet about bit masks, but I'll look for it now

Comment: I don't think that's it, not exactly. You seem to be assuming that `a` has 4 bits (and that therefore, so does `~a`), which is wrong to begin with, before any masking happens. The masking is necessary because that's wrong: there are more bits, and they're not zero yet, the masking is used to make all the unwanted bits zero.

Comment: This program concentrates on the lowest 4 bits of an int, but the other bits still *exist* and they can get in the way especially if the extra bits aren't zero. In many cases the extra bits [are harmless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34377711/555045) but notably not when indexing into an array.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. @harold, according to your reading recommendation, seems that there is garbage in the upper bits, which is the reason I cannot perform a few operations without ensuring that the upper bits are zeroed. Initially, `a` had the value I pretend it to have, so I assume no garbage existed, is it right?. But upon negating it, though, is it possible that some garbage appears in the upper bits? Where does this garbage come from?

Comment: The upper bits of `a` are zeroes, so the upper bits of `~a` are ones. BTW you can do a lot of operations on integers that have garbage in the upper bits (as the linked QA shows), but the garbage must be removed before using the integer as an index in an array.

Comment: Oh, I got it. The inversion of the upper bits to 1 also answers why the code was trying to access the index -4 of the array when not using the `0x0f` mask: because of the two's complement. Thank you so much, @harold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [harold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555045/harold) for their [explanation in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77567806/bit-masking-garbage-bits?noredirect=1#comment136747493_77567806) and [pointed QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34377712/17781072) that, with a few other resources, made me understand it.

---

One cannot assume that the compiler inverts just the significant bits upon negation. Ex.: `000...01010` has the same value as `1010`, but its complement is not the inversion of just those significant digits, it's `111...10101`. Therefore, the complement of `a` in the code provided is actually `111...1100`.

Consider N the width of bits that represent an integer type: in Java, all integers are signed values, so their range varies from -2<sup>N-1</sup> to 2<sup>N-1</sup>-1, and the most significant bit (MSB), the one in the N<sup>th</sup> position, determines the sign of an integer. When turned on, the MSB represents negative values.

So when `a` was inverted, its value became `111...1100` which is equivalent to -4 in decimal, because of the way Java and most other programming languages represent their integers: using an encoding known as [two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049774/17781072), which means that "*negative numbers are represented by inverting (changing 1’s to 0’s and vice versa) all of the bits in a value, then adding 1 to the result. To decode a negative number, first invert all of the bits, then add 1.*" (Herbert Schildt, Java: The Complete Reference 12th).

Finally, by decoding `~a` you'll see that it represents -4, in decimal, and that's why, without using a bit mask ([What is bit masking?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10493411/17781072)), it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with the message "Index -4 out of bounds for length 16". So the bitwise AND between `~a` and `0xf` is transforming all but the four rightmost bits of `~a` to 0, to then be assigned to `g`:

```
    ~a:  1111 .... 1100 
   0xf:  0000 .... 1111 (&)
         ------------------
result:  0000 .... 1100
```

That's why `g` requires the `0xf` bitmask in order to successfully access the 12<sup>th</sup> index of the array.